# Couldn't get metadata from remote machine but local is fine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking, tcp

So here's my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>

  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
    <bindings />
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CrossDomainServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AService.AServBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService.MyServ">
        <endpoint address="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AService.IAServ" isSystemEndpoint="false" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

As you can see there's nothing special. I just want to create simple service with tcp binding and ability to transmit metadata information. I had success with same one using `basicHttpBinding` and everything was going OK. 
Here's the code that creates service instance with baseaddress:

```
Console.WriteLine("net.tcp://" + _bindAddress + "/");
ServiceHost myserviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri(String.Concat("net.tcp://", _bindAddress, "/")));
myserviceHost.Open();
```

`_bindAddress` is a string that comes from custom service configuration XML file. I'm trying to bind service to internal network interface at IP address `172.19.0.102:8733`. Then I'm trying to get service metadata using WcfTestClient from address `127.0.0.1:8733` on service's machine and everyting is fine. But then I trying to obtain service's metadata on target remote machine over Internet I getting the `TCP error with code 10051`. 
My goal is to get service working and publishing metadata over Internet for any client. There's no issues with firewalls and other network stuff. It seems like I need some configuration edits to allow service share metadata with everyone.
Thanks in advance!

---

*POST EDIT:*

Here is my tryings:
1) Service configured to bind at `172.19.0.102:8733`.
A. WCF Test Client tryes to obtain metadata on hosted machine from address `net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8733/` failed with `TCP error code 10061`.
B. On the same machine WCF Client tryes to obtain metadata from `net.tcp://172.19.0.102:8733` and it's working OK.
C. WCF Test Client tryes to obtain metadata on another machine in LAN from address `net.tcp://192.168.1.2:8733/` (it's service's machine IP address) gives an error `TCP error code 10061`.

Answer (score 0):

That error means: *Network is unreachable* an that is most probably what really happens. Your IP address belongs to private network range and these addresses can never be addressed directly from Internet / WAN - they are only for local usage in LAN. To access such address over internet you must configure your publicly exposed router / gateway to accept the connection and forward it to your internal device = NAT / port forwarding, etc.

Comment: I setup ASP .NET (udpate service reference) for that service and then upload this site to hoster machine. Then on hoster machine I have configured web.config address to point to static ip address where service hosted and I get this error again. I know that class B network addresses won't be reached by clients, so I edit config file to connect straight to service's machine. And even if I try get metadata from almost same service (using basicHttpBinding) configured to bind at 172.19.0.102:8732 it works fine.

Comment: I'm little bit lost in your description of what is accessible and what is not and how your application is deployed. So can you access the net.tcp service locally (on hosted machine) from both loopback and real address? Can you access the service from other machine in the same network? Does it work with real client instead of test client? Can you diagnose the TCP traffic on the hosted and client machine to see details. Are there any network devices involved in the communication? Can you simply telnet to the port? It looks more like diagnosing network issue.

Comment: OK Ladislav please see my post edit to get additional test results.